Riesz Lemma holds for r=1 iff every $f\in X'$ attains its norm on the unit sphere of $X$
The exercise is given in the following way:

Exercise : The Riesz Lemma with $r=1$ holds in $X$ iff every $f\in X'$ iff every $f\in X'$ attains its norm on the unit sphere of $X$.

I already have proved the result:

Result 1: The Riesz Lemma $r=1$ holds  in $X$ iff for every closed subspace $Y$ of $X$, there are $x\in X$ and $y_0\in Y$ s.t. $\Vert x- y_0\Vert =dist(x,Y)>0$.

and I also know from the application of Hahn Banach Extension Theorem:

Result 2: Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of $X$ and $a\in X$ but $a\notin Y$. Then there is some $f\in X'$ s.t. $f_{|Y}=0,f(a)=dist(a,Y)$ and $\Vert f \Vert =1.$

I am missing something to prove the above exercise. Please help me to connect the missing steps. And, I have found the question in an older post, but they all use the reflexivity of dual space, a concept I don't know until now. This exercise is given in Hahn Banach chapter, before the reflexivity. THANK YOU!!!

this answers it. It mentions reflexivity, but it is not used in what you want. That every $f\in X'$ attains its norm is called James' property there
